# Applying round function in select statement to only numeric values and leaving character values as it is in a single column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use round function or any other function on a column in oracle table having both character values and numeric decimal values. It should make changes to numeric values and should leave retrieve character/string values as it is.

I tried but it says invalid number.

For eg:

```
column(in table)
(1.7313883, 1.7313883, 1.63721,nm,nm, nm)
```

After retrieval reqd:

```
column/required(1.73x, 1.73x, 1.63x, nm, nm, nm)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether the string is numeric (for instance with a regular expression) and if so, convert it to a number to do the rounding, and then convert it back to string.

Here is how it could look for `mytable.col`:

```
select case when regexp_like(col, '\d+(\.\d+)?') 
          then to_char(round(to_number(col), 2)) || 'x'
          else col
       end
from   mytable
```

NB: This assumes the NLS decimal separator is set to `.` (the default). If not, extend the `to_char` call to:

```
to_char(round(to_number(col, '99999D99999999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'''), 2))
```

#### Explanation

The regular expression broken down:

- `\d`: matches a digit. It is short for `[0-9]`.
- `+`: one or more of the previous
- `(    )?`: optional part of the match -- used here to optionally allow for a decimal part in the number
- `\.`: match a literal dot. The backslash is needed because `.` has a special meaning in regular expressions.

`regexp_like` is the regular expression variant of the `like` operator: it allows you to test a string against a pattern. The pattern here only allows for unsigned integers or unsigned decimal numbers in plain notation (not scientific notation).

Comment: Bingo. It Worked. Thanks a lot Trincot. I would really appreciate if i you could tell what regexp_like(col, '\d+(\.\d+)?') function did here?

Comment: You're welcome ;-) I added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT To_char(1.854754857, 'B999999999999999999990.999') FROM DUAL;
SELECT To_char(1.854754857, 'B999999999999999999990.99') FROM DUAL;
SELECT To_char(1.854754857, 'B999999999999999999990.9') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Translate is another option mentioned at:

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php

Following code works in Oracle12C:

```
WITH TABLE1
     AS (SELECT '1.7313883' VAL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '1.7313884' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'nm' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'other' FROM DUAL)
SELECT DECODE (TRANSLATE (VAL, ' +-.0123456789', ' '),
               NULL, TO_CHAR (ROUND (TO_NUMBER (VAL), 2)) || 'x' ,
               VAL) new_val
  FROM TABLE1;
```

with the result:

```
NEW_VAL
1.73x
1.73x
nm
other
```

Comment: This would need an extra safety to avoid errors on values with two or more dots, like '1.7313.884'